# vue draggable, added method not invoked

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

Vue draggable added/removed/moved methods not invoked when item dragged/moved. Can you please let me know what are the code changes to make these methods invoked

```
<v-expansion-panel-data
          >
            <draggable
              v-model="item.children"
              tag="v-list"              
              :added="added"
              :removed="removed"
              :moved="moved"
              :move="checkMove"
            >
              <v-list-item
                v-for="child item.children"
                :key="child.name"                
              >
                <v-icon>
                  mdi-drag
                </v-icon>
                <div class="pl-2">
                  {{ child.name }}
                </div>
              </v-list-item>
            </draggable>
          </v-expansion-panel-data>

methods: {
    checkMove(evt) {
      console.log('checkmove..')
      // return (evt.draggedContext.element.name!=='apple');
    },
    added(newIndex, element) {
      console.log('moved..')
    },
    removed(oldIndex, element) {
      console.log('removed..')
    },
    moved(newIndex, oldIndex, element) {
      console.log('moved..')
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@` decorator (also known as `v-on:`) instead of `:` (`v-bind:`) for listening to events fired by a vue component.

Try this:

```
        <draggable
          v-model="item.children"
          tag="v-list"              
          @added="added"
          @removed="removed"
          @moved="moved"
          @move="checkMove"
        >
```

Also check this out for further reference on those events:

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events